# Why we write $z=x+iy$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Though I know $z=x+iy$ is representation of complex number is there any relation of $x+iy$ with z-axis, so that a plane forms as $x+iy-z=0$ that means $z=x+iy$ ?

Comment: I think that $z$ just represents an arbitrary number, nothing to do with the z-axis. You can write $a = x + iy$ as well.

Comment: It's really saying that $\vec z = (x, y)$. So nothing to do with a third axis.

Comment: It the letter that follows  $x$ and $y$ had been $k$, very probably a generic complex number would have ben denoted $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need not write a complex number in such a way; however, it is convenient.

The important thing is that we consider $z \in \mathbb{C}$ as a complex number with a *real* and an *imaginary* component. We can write any of the following things:

$$\begin{align*}
z &= a+bi, \\
z &= \begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{pmatrix}, \\
z &= \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\exp\left( i \arctan \frac{b}{a} + 2ik\pi\right), k \in \mathbb{Z}, \\
z &= (a,b)
\end{align*}$$
and probably others that I am forgetting.

What matters is that we recognize that a complex number has these real and imaginary components, and that we can do arithmetic on them in a way that makes sense.

Given $z_1$ and $z_2$, we want to have $\textrm{Re}(z_1+z_2) = \textrm{Re}(z_1) + \textrm{Re}(z_2)$, for instance. The $a+bi$ notation guarantees this property using our familiar notion of addition.

Likewise, we want to be able to multiply in a way that makes sense. The $a+bi$ notation is bad for multiplying several complex numbers. However, the matrix forms and exponential forms simplify this quite a bit!

Often times in mathematics, when we explore structures that are more complicated than what we're used to dealing with in every day life (i.e. natural numbers), we want to find equivalent operations that work with our familiar operations. Under ideal circumstances, we want to claim that adding rationals should act like adding naturals. Adding complex numbers should act like adding reals. And so forth.

We don't always get these properties. But when we do, we often overload our conventional notation. The addition in $z_1+z_2$ is not necessarily the same operation as performing $1+2$, but since all its properties coincide with what we know for adding reals, we can treat it as the same thing.

Therefore, writing $z=a+bi$ is a convenient shorthand notation of saying, "a complex number has a real an imaginary component, and it can be written as the addition of those components, where the addition we use has all the same properties as the addition we've known since elementary school."